# Find a total number of text boxes on a web page in Java - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am looking for some help as am just getting into a web automation using Selenium with the Java bindings. I am trying to find the total number of text boxes on a web page, I have the code working for checking `@type=text`. The code is below, however, when I try to find text boxes by:

`"//input[@type='text'[@class='dijitReset dijitInputInner']"` and it fails. The full code is below.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//Launch browser
driver.get("http://localhost/2010A15/?p=register");

//Create Web element list

java.util.List<WebElement> textboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("dijitReset dijitInputInner']"));

System.out.println(textboxes.size());

for(int i=1; i<=textboxes.size(); i=i+1);
{
    System.out.println(textboxes.size());
}

driver.close();  





}
```

}

Error Message:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector
>   dijitReset dijitInputInner'] is either invalid or does not result in a
>   WebElement. The following error occurred: InvalidSelectorError: Unable
>   to locate an element with the xpath expression dijitReset
>   dijitInputInner'] because of the following error: SyntaxError: The
>   expression is not a legal expression.

I presume the error is telling me that `dijitReset dijitInputInner` is not valid and that's why it isn't working, however, I am unsure on how to fix this. Any help? As the class of the item in inspect element is: `dijitReset dijitInputInner`.

Comment: You appear to have XPath syntax errors in both of your XPath expressions. The first one is missing a `]` to close the first predicate. The second one seems more seriously jumbled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only want to count the numbers of elements (textboxes) than you can avoid looping each webelement by using size()

```
int boxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@class='dijitReset dijitInputInner']")).size();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElements> totalTextboxes = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='text']"));
System.out.println(totalTextboxes.size());
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> textBoxes=driver.findElements(By.xpath(//input[@type='text']));
i=textBoxes.size(); 

List<WebElement> textBoxes=driver.findElements(By.xpath(//input));
for(WebElement each:textBoxes){

   String local=each.getAttribute("type");
    if(local!=null && local.equals("text") i++;
}
```